# echo $PATH literally prints "$PATH" as the output

Tags: bash, file, unix, echo

I want to go through a text file, that contains one command per line. I want to read each line, execute each command, and then save the output to a file.

The part of the script that's giving me problems is:

```
echo COMMAND LOG > $dest/command.log

echo ====== >> $dest/command.log

while IFS= read -r v

do
    echo ====== >> $dest/command.log

    echo COMMAND: $v >> $dest/command.log

    echo ======OUTPUT====== >> $dest/command.log

    $v >> $dest/command.log

    echo ====== >> $dest/command.log

done < "$commands"
```

It works great for everything except "echo $PATH" which generates:

```
======

COMMAND: echo $PATH

======OUTPUT======

$PATH
```

Is there anyway to get it to work properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your other commands (except for `$PATH`) get interpreted ? Also, showing a sample of your input text file and output could be useful.

Comment: Yes, everything else (for example, "ls -l /etc/" gets interpreted correctly.

Comment: The input file looks like this: 
echo $PATH
ls -l /etc/
ps -ef

and the output should be like the one I displayed, but for example, for "ls -l /etc/" it displays:

==============================================
COMMAND: ls -l /etc/
====================OUTPUT====================
total 44
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 GLENNAR Domain Users    0 May 25 13:22 alternatives
-rw-r--r--  1 GLENNAR Domain Users  856 May 25 13:23 bash.bash_logout
...etc..etc... (leaving out the rest due to length)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected, because you are fetching a file line by line, you got strings, not variables. `$v` is a `"$PATH"` string, that's all.

You must `eval` your string to get associated variable's value:

```
echo COMMAND: $(eval $v) >> $dest/command.log
```

Comment: This... worked quite well, except for the fact that now I'm not getting any linebreaks on any single command. (So for example, "ls -l /etc/" which used to print into the file correctly, is now all in a single line)

Comment: NEVER MIND, made it work!
(eval $v) >> $dest/command.log did the trick, thanks!

Comment: @arount you should select this as the winner.  BTW, I find what you are doing odd, can you explain why you want to just issue commands like this ?